# Event on RecyclerView items affects multiple rows at a time instead of one specific row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, event-listener

To summarize my app fragment, I have a `RecyclerView` who's size is dynamic, and relative to a `ViewModel` variable (when this variable changes, RecyclerView's list of items grows or shrinks respectively).

Each row has a couple buttons.  Each of those buttons has a `OnClickListener` on it.  (When clicked, the button disappears).

**Problem:**
When a button is clicked, not only that button disappears, but every additional multiple of 7 (index-wise) disappears as well.

For example:  You press a button in row 1, and the exact same thing happens in row 8, 15, and 22, even though you only clicked row 1.

I am currently passing a listener through my fragment's `onViewCreated` method to a private listener variable in the adapter (listener's set in the constructor).

I'll show the relavent bits of my Fragment and Adapter:

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyModel model;
    private ArrayList<Data> dataList;
    private int numberOfDataItems;

    private RecyclerView content;
    private RecycleAdapter adapter;

    private View.OnClickListener onItemClickLIstener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            // This is the buggy bit
            viewHolder.myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            Data data = dataList.get(position);
            // TODO: eventually do some logic here with the data
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        content = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        model.createDataList(numberOfDataItems);
        dataList = model.getDataList();

        adapter = new RecycleAdapter(dataList);
        content.setAdapter(adapter);
        content.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data> dataList;
    private View.OnClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Button myButton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            myButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
            myButton.setTag(this);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context conext = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View DataView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(dataView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Data data = dataList.get(position);
        // Do stuff with data

        myButton.setText(data);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener itemClickListener) {
        onItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing to your onClick listener the `viewHolder` while doing that

```
   myButton.setTag(this);  // this = viewHolder
```

The viewHolder is a recyclable view. So, you cannot treat this view as a unique item view.
Remember that a viewHolder is created to be reused by other items. That's why you see your action reflected in other items.

**The solution:**

Set to your tag, not the `viewHolder`, but the item position.
Then, in your `Data` structure, you should add variables to remember which buttons should be displayed or not.

```
class Data {
    ...
    String text;
    boolean btnVisible;
}
```

In `View.OnClickListener` you should set these variables values.

```
private View.OnClickListener onItemClickLIstener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position =  (int)view.getTag();
        Data data = dataList.get(position);
        data.btnVisible = false;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // TODO: eventually do some logic here with the data
    }
}
```

Then, in your `onBindViewHolder` you should set the button text and the button visibility state depending on variables in `Data` structure.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Data data = dataList.get(position);
    // Do stuff with data

    myButton.setText(data.text);
    myButton.setVisibility(?data.btnVisible:VISIBLE:GONE);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean using the position parameter within the `onBindViewHolder` method instead of the constructor to set the tag?  I've heard different things, but I suppose after researching a bit more it seems this is the standard practice

Answer (score 2):

please use below snip for get exact position,
setTag(); to the View and then on Click time get that tag value using getTag();
for perfect position.

```
    myViewHolder.ivVoiceThumb.setTag(pos);
    myViewHolder.ivVoiceThumb.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        int getPos = (int)view.getTag();
    });
```